# How do I set http in monit?

Tags: monit

[Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/): the monit HTTP interface is not enabled, please add the 'set httpd' statement and use the 'allow' option to allow monit to connect

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

You need to configure monit web interface in file `monitrc`.

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/monitrc
```

There is already configuration for emabling web interface but it is commented bydefault. 
You can comment out following lines already present in `monitrc` file. You can change bydefault username and password for security reasons.

```
set httpd port 2812
     allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
```

Reload monit configuration after editing configuration file.

```
sudo monit reload
```